# Django Session with Memcached or ElastiCache, does the Django code need to be changed?

Tags: django, session, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have an app using DB as session backend, and I realize that Django allows a Memcached-like (memcached, ElastiCache) session backend.

Reading the doc at Django site, I found the setting file can specify that change. My question is whether my view logic code files need any change.

Answer (score 1):

No. You shouldn't have to change anything. If you deploy the code on a live site, active sessions will be lost (all users will be logged out).